# How to see the default gateway of mobile network?

Tags: networking, gateway

Android version 13
One UI Core version 5.1
Model code SM-A045FZKGXID
Kernel version 4.19.191-26097594-abA045FXXU3cWG1

The following is a history of my useless attempts, which raised more questions than I was looking for. :)

The question seems so dumb I fear I am asking in the wrong community, never the less I have been struggling the whole day to find the answer to this. After hours of googling and ChatGPT I randomly found my IP address, instead of being among network-related settings, was among "status information" (why?)

I must tell you that I have no experience on Android devices whatsoever but I am a Linux enthusiast and therefore thought about checking the network configuration files in `/etc`, I downloaded a terminal and then another but I couldn't go anywhere: almost all commands are unusable. I understood that Android did some kind of restriction on the file system, even reading files is a hassle. `ip` and `netstat` yielded errors.

I decided to unlock the "developer options", connect my phone to the PC, and try to navigate it from there. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the root folder / all I could find was 'Internal Storage' with its DCIM, Documents... subfolders.

I read that through some apps, the default gateway can be obtained. I think though that if apps can do it I should be able to do it as well, or at least understand how.

I thank you for your time and understanding, any explanation concerning any matter I exposed above is appreciated, even if not directly answering my question, I am keen to learn and expand my knowledge.

Comment: Android bases on Linux, but it is not like a common Linux distro. If you want an environment that is more like Linux install Termux from FDroid store (not the outdated Play Store version).

Comment: I thought Termux was a terminal, how can a terminal change my platform? shouldn't only offer a way to interact with the underlying environment?

Comment: Termux contains a package manager to install common Linux tools compiled for Android and arm[64]. Of course everything is running in the context of the app user, so all commands which require root or direct device access will not work.

Comment: What have you tried the whole day? Did you check the output of `dumpsys connectivity | grep CONNECTED` and `ip route`?

Comment: dumpsys and ip are both yielding permission denied errors.
su outputs: inaccessible or not found.
I fear termux is not going to work either, since the files that hold the network informations are non readable.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably find this easier if you turn on USB debugging and work in the ADB shell from a computer. I came to Android from Linux, and find this a more familiar environment than termux.

However, the ADB shell environment is not normal Linux, although it is Linux-like. The shell is different ([mksh](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/shell_and_utilities/README.md)), the command-line tools are provided by [toybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toybox), and the filesystem layout is very different. You can run `netstat` and `ip`, though.

Answer (score 0):

I use a 3rd party app called [FING](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en&gl=US) to do a network scan and then I usually find the router/access point IP.

Alternatively (but this doesn't always show up):

Settings -> Connections -> Wi-Fi -> find the network you want and click the Gears button to the right of it. Now there may be a button that shows up called **Manage Router**

[image]
If it shows up, you can click on it and it will open a webpage to the IP address (management page) of your router (default gateway in most home-routers)

Comment: I am looking for my isp gateway for mobile connection, not wifi. I will look into FING tho, thanks.